# Invalid Firebase Database path: #. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[enter link description here](https://facebook.com)

I can not even figure out where my error is coming from. Please kindly help. I think it has to do with the replace strings I dont know.I am working on a firebase project.

[image]

```
private void getContactsList() {
    final ArrayList<Contact> mContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    mContacts.add(new Contact(mPref.getString(KEY_NAME, null), mPref.getString(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, null)));

    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Cursor contacts = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    // use the cursor to access the contacts
    while (contacts.moveToNext()) {

        //get display name
        final String name = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        //get mobile number
        String mobileNo = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        // trim mobile number
        mobileNo = mobileNo.replace(" ", "");
        mobileNo = mobileNo.replace("-", "");
        mobileNo = mobileNo.replace("+233", "");

        if (mobileNo.length() > 11 && mobileNo.charAt(0) == '0') {
            mobileNo = mobileNo.substring(1);
        }

        final String finalPhoneNumber = mobileNo;

        //check if user exist or not
        mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(mobileNo)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                            //user not exists
                            if (!isContainsContact(mContacts, finalPhoneNumber)) {
                                mAdapter.addItem(new Contact(name, finalPhoneNumber));
                                mContacts.add(new Contact(name, finalPhoneNumber));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add ur database to the question (upload image to imgur) not Facebook

Comment: The error message is telling you that you're using an invalid character # to build a path to a document.  You will have to debug your code and figure out where the invalid character is coming from.

Comment: it says the error is at    mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(mobileNo)

Comment: Then it makes sense to consider the value of `mobileNo`.

Comment: i already solved this...i jusr relaced the ("#") also with ("")